# performance table join with async javascript and mongoose

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, mongodb, asynchronous

```
var asynclib = require('async');

exports.apiFindNutrients = function(req, res) {
    var ndb = req.params.ndb;

    NutrDefModel.find().limit(30).exec(function(error, nutref) {

            asynclib.mapSeries(nutref, function(ref, callback) {

              NutrModel.find({ Nutr_No: ref.Nutr_No, Ndb_No: ndb }, function(error, nutrient) {

                  console.log(nutrient + 'nutrval: ' + nutrient.Nutr_Val);
                  var result = {
                      Ndb_No: nutrient.Ndb_No,
                      Nutr_No: ref.Nutr_No,
                      Units: ref.Units,
                      Tagname: ref.Tagname,
                      Nutr_Desc: ref.Nutr_Desc,
                      Nutr_Val: nutrient.Nutr_Val
                  };


                      callback(null, result);
                  }
              });

            }, function (err, result) {
                if (err)
                    console.log('async lib ' + err);
                res.send(result);
            });

        }
    });

};
```

I want to join two tables with mongoose, i came up with the above solution but it takes 12 seconds for 70 items in NutrDefModel, when i do limit(30) it takes 1.5 seconds. I need to improve to under 1 seconds.
I am really new to async javascript and mongoose, i barely understand how async library works in this solution, what alternetives do i have with javascript and mongoose.

I've added some indexes it improved performance, but now i have another problem. Above console.log line produces the output:

```
{ Ndb_No: 3198,
  Nutr_No: 318,
  Nutr_Val: '144',
  _id: 5222665eab19d2db1800379d }nutrval: undefined
```

you can see nutrition object contains Nutr_Val but nutrient.Nutr_Val prints undefined. Why?

Comment: You've designed your schemas poorly if you need to Join tables with Mongodb as it doesn't support them efficiently. You'll need to rethink your design.

Comment: I've added some indexes and it works faster but now i have another problem, see edit above.

Comment: Your field name is spelled differently. It must be exact. Case matters.

Comment: Spelling is correct, i checked it many times. I found a similar problem here, but in my case console.log(typeof nutrient) yields object i don't know how to fix it :(
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7922226/why-is-this-object-property-undefined

Comment: What are you actually typing to see the value? `nutrval` is not the same as `Nutr_Val`.

Comment: nutrition.Nutr_Val == undefined??
i think i cannot fix this problem easily, can you provide me a way to join two documents by some field. i don't use ref keyword but its a reference.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend against trying to do a join with MongoDB and would instead investigate options for adjusting your schema and collections to better fit with your query requirements.

The issue you're seeing is that the `find` method returns an array ([docs for query](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html)). If you know there is only a single/exact result, I'd recommend you use `findOne` instead.

```
NutrModel.find({ Nutr_No: ref.Nutr_No, Ndb_No: ndb }, function(error, nutrient) {
     if (err) { console.log('error!'); return; }
     console.log("count: " + nutrient.length);
     for(var i=0, len=nutrient.length; i < length; i++) {
        var onenutrient = nutrient[i];
        // now, do something ...
     } 
     callback(null, result);
   }
);
```

Or, just

```
NutrModel.findOne({ Nutr_No: ref.Nutr_No, Ndb_No: ndb }, function(error, nutrient) {
    if (err) { console.log('error!'); return; }
    // do something with the nutrient
}
```